# Is there a car-friendly way to play music on the iPhone without a car kit?

Tags: iphone, music

I'm wondering if there is a car-friendly way to play music on the iPhone without any type of car kit.  Specifically, I am looking for a way to change tracks without unlocking the phone.  I'm okay with pressing the home button, I just don't want to worry about unlocking the phone.

Some examples would be:
1) Swipe controls accessible from the lockscreen.
2) Shaking/moving the iPhone in a certain way.

I know Siri can do this, but I was hoping there was a way to accomplish this pre-Siri.

The normal music player on the lockscreen is not suitable for driving, as I have to look at the phone to press the touchscreen in the right place.

Comment: Disable locking while in the car?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, not that familiar with iOS.  Can you disable lockscreen? Can you swipe w/ normal music player?

Comment: To disable lockscreen: Settings/General/AutoLock/Never

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get something like [this remote](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000V8RCTS), which has passthrough for any standard 3.5mm audio, and provides volume controls and a clicker remote (just like on Apple's headphones). The clicker can to play, pause, and skip (double click for forward, triple click for backward).

There are other similar products out there, I found a few by searching for "iPhone inline remote".

Comment: It appears that this is a very cheap device (giving a lot of bad reviews).  Perhaps there is a more expensive but better version of this?

Comment: I didn't really look at the reviews, but you're probably right. As I noted, there are other similar products out there, I just picked the first one I found as a representative sample. Actual shopping is left to the reader.